# setting of table header

Tags: php, html, html-table

hi this is my code,

```
$tbl .= 

            <tr><td  width="5%">' . $reqid . '</td>
             <td>' . $name . '</td>
             <td  width="12%">' . $date . '</td>
             <td>' . $start . '</td>
             <td>' . $end . '</td>
             <td>' . $veh_name . '</td>
             <td>' . $reason . '</td>
             <td>' . $status . '</td>
             <td>' . $sup . '</td>
             <td  width="15%">' . $comment . '</td>
        </tr>';
}
```

How can i add a table header?  for every column. i tried to put a header but the header repeats itself at every row of data.

Answer (score 0):

You can add another `<tr></tr>` above the data,and give your `for loop` after this header.

```
<tr>
     <th>Column 1</th>
     <th>Column 2</th>
     <th>Column 3</th>
     <th>Column 4</th>
     <th>Column 5</th>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Place this html **before the loop**. Also remember that for better practice, you can declare your width in the header.

```
<tr>
    <th width="5%">Req ID</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th width="12%">Date</th>
    <th>Start</th>
    <th>End</th>
    <th>Veh Name</th>
    <th>Reason</th>
    <th>Status</th>
    <th>Sup</th>
    <th width="15%">Comment</th>
</tr>
```

Comment: @Sukiyam, Vote up and tick if you find my answer helpful. :)

Answer (score 0):

you are missing `'` from starting.

```
  $tbl .= 

                '<tr><td  width="5%">' . $reqid . '</td>
                 <td>' . $name . '</td>
                 <td  width="12%">' . $date . '</td>
                 <td>' . $start . '</td>
                 <td>' . $end . '</td>
                 <td>' . $veh_name . '</td>
                 <td>' . $reason . '</td>
                 <td>' . $status . '</td>
                 <td>' . $sup . '</td>
                 <td  width="15%">' . $comment . '</td>
            </tr>';
```